# fastest multi-threaded iterative sparse solver on CPU?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, sparse-matrix, iteration, intel-mkl

Intel MKL library offers optimized set of threaded functions, but for case of iterative sparse solver (ISS), the preconditioned conjugate gradient method does not seem to be straightforward to be threaded.

To be more precise, using preconditioning techniques such as incomplete Cholesky factorization or ILU, at some point sparse triangular solvers are required, but corresponding MKL function to perform triangular solving `mkl_cspblas_?csrtrsv` is not threaded. My question is if there are any sparse solver libraries to beat the current version of MKL (which is not fully threaded) on multi-core processors?

Comment: Has MKL improved on the latest versions? Have you tried linking it to MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it beats MKL - it is a research project after all - but there is a mixed-mode [OpemMP+MPI branch of PETSc](https://bitbucket.org/ggorman/petsc-3.3-omp) available. In my group's experimentation with the SpMV implementation it scaled well for simple matrices, but not for the more complex ones we deal with regularly. You may have better luck, depending on your problem.

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: @StepanYakovenko Thanks for pointing this out.
This work may have been integrated into PETSc; See https://petsc.org/release/manual/getting_started/#sec-cpu-openmp